# Review examples for all application

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

I am using Microsoft LUIS in one of my application in which we are going to provide facility to review failed utterances/examples.

Currently I am able to do this for single LUIS application using [Review labeled examples](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0a) API in which I provide single application id.

Now I need to review labeled examples for all of my LUIS application but I didn't find any suitable API.

Is there any single API in which I can pass array of application id's and get the review data? or I need to call [Review labeled examples](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0a) API each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no provision to review labeled examples for all of your LUIS apps using the LUIS Programmatic API. You will need to call the [Review labeled examples](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0a/console) API for each LUIS app by passing the appId to return the examples to be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this for each LUIS app.